# GRASS init error in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, installation, ubuntu

Every time when I start my QGIS I see the following message:

> GRASS init error: Problem in GRASS initialization, GRASS provider and
>   plugin will not work : Module built against version $Revision: 64733 $
>   but trying to use version $Revision: 67364 $. You need to rebuild
>   GRASS GIS or untangle multiple installations.

This problem has appeared on Friday. And I am not able to find out what caused this issue. I work in Ubuntu Trusty Tahr 14.04 LTS. QGIS version is 2.12.3-Lyon.

Could someone help me to solve the problem with QGIS and GRASS?

Comment: I can confirm that this error also occurs on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: I had to uninstall GRASS using apt:
sudo apt-get remove qgis-plugin-grass

Comment: Have tried the nightly versions of QGIS and Grass71 but still displays the same error. No such issues with the same installations from 'Osgeo4w' on Windows.

Comment: This problem is also occurring in LTR version 2.18.27.

Answer (score 1):

According to

https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2016-February/073655.html

... "QGIS was built against a earlier version of GRASS." They suggest to use the nightly builds of QGIS.